# how to sum up supply counts within day range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have columns : ID, supply counts,Days.

I want to give value 1 for ID that has supply counts >=100 from days 1 to 60;else 0.

Days range(-30,100)

each ID had a row of record on the day he got supplies.eg ID(1), supply count(10), on day (-5).

what I tried:

```
df.loc[(0<df.days)&（df.days<=60)]

groupby('id').sum()

np.where((supply counts>100) , '1', '0')
```

the problem is that if any id who have no record from days0 to 60 , id would be missing.

data sample.

```
  id    supply  days
    1   15   -10
    1   20    5
    1   325   15
    2   10    -20
    2   50    10
    3   20    -30






id  y            
1   1
2   0
```

Comment: You should format your code and also provide some sample data.

Comment: Can you add expected output from your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then aggregate `sum` only for `supply` column, and because possible some `id` values are filter out, add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of original. Last [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame` and add new `y` column with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract `supply`:

```
df1 = df[(df.days > 0)&(df.days<=60)]
df2=df1.groupby('id')['supply'].sum().reindex(df['id'].unique(), fill_value=-1).reset_index()
df2['y'] = np.where(df2.pop('supply') > 100, 1, 0)
print (df2)
   id   y
0   1   1
1   2   0
2   3   0
```

EDIT: If need remove filter out `id` rows:

```
df1 = df[(df.days > 0)&(df.days<=60)]
df2=df1.groupby('id', as_index=False)['supply'].sum()
df2['y'] = np.where(df2.pop('supply') > 100, 1, 0)
print (df2)
   id  y
0   1  1
1   2  0
```

Alternative solution:

```
df2 = (df.query("0 < days <=60") 
         .groupby('id')['supply'].sum()
         .reindex(df['id'].unique(), fill_value=-1)
         .rename('y')
         .gt(100)
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index()
       )
print (df2)
   id  y
0   1  1
1   2  0
2   3
```

---

```
df2 = (df.query("0 < days <=60") 
         .groupby('id')['supply'].sum()
         .rename('y')
         .gt(100)
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index()
       )
print (df2)
   id  y
0   1  1
1   2  0
```

Comment: Same situation as df.loc[(0<df.days)&（df.days<=60)]
. 3  id are missing after groupby, 3 out of 14000.

Comment: @Yuuu - So what is expected output in this situtation? New row with `3` and no values `suply` and days?

Comment: I got all id if I enlarge my day range in the conditions.

Comment: @Yuuu - I change data sample in your question. Can you add expcted output? How should looks data finally?

Comment: @jazrael I am some confused about your question. I guess the problem is that some id are filter out becuase those id have no record of supply on days between 0 and 60.  I check shape right after groupby('id). In some range, id are missing.

Comment: @Yuuu - Yes, and if check your data, there is last row with 3, and then should be removed, because conditions. so my question is how looks data finally after all your operation? Because you are right, last id = 3 is removed, because filter. But if need it, then possible add it? so my question is how looks data finally, please add it to question. I remove data from 6 rows for easy sum manually.

Comment: Amazing, fill value with -1. genius. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The way i understood it, may be this is what you need.

```
s = (df.Days>0) & (df.Days<=60)
df['ID_new']= np.where ((s) & (df.supply_counts>=100), 1,0)
```

**Input**

```
   ID   supply_counts   Days
0   1   135             -15
1   1   70               67
2   1   90               38
3   1   80               49
4   1   68               71
5   2   116              85
6   1   81               91
7   2   62               15
8   1   112               1 
9   1   115               65
10  2   87               51
11  1   105              -9
12  1   107               2
13  2   66               79
14  2   92               46
```

**Output**

```
    ID  supply_counts   Days    ID_new
0   1   135             -15     0
1   1   70               67     0
2   1   90               38     0
3   1   80               49     0
4   1   68               71     0
5   2   116              85     0
6   1   81               91     0
7   2   62               15     0
8   1   112               1     1
9   1   115               65    0
10  2   87               51     0
11  1   105              -9     0
12  1   107               2     1
13  2   66               79     0
14  2   92               46     0
```

If the result is needed as sum of each id to be 1 if sum of supply_counts >100, Then the code below will work.

```
df2 = df.groupby('id').sum().reset_index()
s = (df2.days>0) & (df2.days<=60)
df2['y']= np.where ((s) & (df2.supply>=100), 1,0)
df2[['id','y']]
```

**Output**

```
   id   y
0   1   1
1   2   0
2   3   0
```

Comment: what I want is give 1 for each id if sum of supply_counts >100 .